# Vala memory management

Tags: c, memory-management, vala

I am going to call a Vala function from C, and I have a question about memory management.
The function looks like this in Vala:

```
int[] GetNumbers();
```

and is translated by `valac` to C like this

```
gint* GetNumbers(int* result_length1);
```

When the above function gets called from C, is the caller responsible for freeing the `gint*` array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Vala question! How cool!

Vala has a useful `-C` option that allows you to take a peek at the C-code it generates. This function, for example...

```
int[] GetNumbers() {
    return new int[] {1,2,3};
}
```

...when compiled with...

```
valac -C -c test.vala
```

...will reveal the following C-code (in `test.c`)...

```
gint* GetNumbers (int* result_length1) {
    gint* result = NULL;
    gint* _tmp0_ = NULL;
    gint* _tmp1_;
    result = (_tmp1_ = (_tmp0_ = g_new0 (gint, 3), _tmp0_[0] = 1, _tmp0_[1] = 2, _tmp0_[2] = 3, _tmp0_), *result_length1 = 3, _tmp1_);
    return result;
}
```

Note the `g_new0`; so yes, you want to `g_free` it.

Even if you're just going by the header file, and can't be bothered to look at every implementation, it looks like the same rules apply as in C: if it ain't `const`, free it.